# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection

Tags: jdbc, websphere-liberty

I am trying to use WAS liberty rutime profile with eclipse Luna.

My environment:

> - Window 7
> - Eclipse luna
> - Websphere application server tools V8.5 plugin
> - Websphere liberty profile

My application using spring framework 2.5, and configuration file as below.

> ```
> <!-- For Oracle and Websphere; you need to use this lob handler definition instead of defaultLobHandler. Because of differences in Oracle's Blob objects. -->
> <bean id="oracleLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler" >
>     <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor" >
>         <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor"/>
>     </property>
> </bean>
> ```

however when I deploy my application into Liberty Profile (LP). for some reason the class can not be loaded properly.

I can find this class in com.ibm.ws.jdbc_1.0.8.jar file, and this jar file located under {server.home}/lib folder. As I understand this library should be loaded automatically.

The detail of error log:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oracleLobHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dataAccessContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor#fff379a3' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor] while setting bean property 'nativeJdbcExtractor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor#fff379a3' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dataAccessContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor because WebSphere API classes are not available: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2388)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor because WebSphere API classes are not available: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1004)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor because WebSphere API classes are not available: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor.<init>(WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
```

Any ideas on this issue really appreciate. I really got pain with this one.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the jdbc feature enabled in your server.xml? If you have a recent Liberty installation, I would recommend enabling the webProfile-6.0 feature, which is a combination of many commonly used features.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I still got same error. but I got some workaround solution by removing "oracleLobHandler"
from configuration file, because I realized that this bean not being used in my application anymore.

Comment: my server.xml as below.

`<featureManager>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
        <feature>webProfile-6.0</feature>
    </featureManager>`

Answer (score 2):

`com.ibm.ws.jdbc_1.0.8.jar` is OSGi bundle, and package you are referring is not exported, so it is not available for application classes.

I assume that you need that to get to the native connection, for that you have two options:

- use the JDBC API `unwrap()` method, like for example [connection.unwrap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Wrapper.html#unwrap%28java.lang.Class%29). See some examples for connection and prepareStatement [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21577331)
- Update to Spring 3.0.5 or higher and use [OracleJdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/nativejdbc/OracleJdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor.html) instead of `WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor` (I didn't test that, but should work in theory).

Answer (score 1):

change：

class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor" />

to：

class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor" />

Comment: this worked for me for an old project using WebSphere dependencies, any clue on the differences between using WebShere vs SimpleNative?